# Drawing line to QImage

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, qimage

I am trying to draw line to QImage and show it in Qlabel. However I have some issues that I cannot solve.

```
    QPixmap px;
    px.fromImage (imgRaw);  // define in header file QImage imgRaw; 

    QPainter p (&px);
    p.setPen (Qt::red);

    p.drawLine (mouseStart_X, mouseStart_Y, mouseReleased_X, mouseReleased_Y);
    p.end ();

    ui->lblRightImg->setPixmap (px);
    ui->lblRightImg->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
    ui->lblRightImg->setScaledContents(true);
```

When I used this code above it gives such error :

```
    QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
    QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
    QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted
```

Then I change my code because it tries to draw in null pixmap so after changing code like this:

```
    QPixmap px(100, 100);
    px.fromImage (imgRaw);  // define in header file QImage imgRaw;
```

Then it gives noisy image(black and gray broken image)

Could you please help me to solve this issue ?

EDIT :

Also tried:

```
QPixmap px = QPixmap::fromImage (imgRaw);
```

Then it gives same image without any drawing..

Comment: I am sorry that I forget to mention about this. I also tried your solution but after that it does not draw anything. I get original image again.

Comment: is your app multithreaded?

Comment: I am drawing this line after I emit signals from mousepressed..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fromImage` is a static function of QPixmap and does not affect your 'object', it returns the pixmap you want. Try using following code to initialize your pixmap:

```
QPixmap px = QPixmap::fromImage(imgRaw);
```

Comment: Try to draw a line from pos(0,0) to pos(px.width(),px.height()) just to get sure that the problem is not the values you're passing. Furthermore try to remove the `p.end()` or to move it after the `setPixmap`-call

Comment: Whats with the "alternative" drawLine?? What are the values of mouseStart_X, mouseStart_Y, mouseReleased_X, mouseReleased_Y and the size of the image?

Comment: You are right. problem is about x,y coordinates I changed it to (50, 50, 100, 100) and see that there is something wrong.. Thank you for your help.